# Disappearing author names in IEEEtran conference template without removing them

Tags: ieeetran

i want to give my conference paper for review, for this i need to remove all 6 author names and this is effecting my figures tables. i am just trying to color the author names white but its not working.

```
enter code here\author{\color{white}
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Abu Yousuf}
    \IEEEauthorblockN{dept. of Electrical and Electronic\\ Engineering\\ International Islamic University\\ Chittagong\\ Chittagong, Bangladesh\\ kawsireeeiiuc@gmail.com}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Rashel Mohammad Khokan}
    \IEEEauthorblockN{dept. of Electrical and Electronic\\ Engineering\\ International Islamic University\\ Chittagong\\ Chittagong, Bangladesh\\ rashel.eee13@gmail.com}
    \and....
```

}

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Rather than a code snippet, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that includes the exact class and options you are using.

Comment: Does \phantom{...} work?